# VS Code on Ubuntu - Can't see menu bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

We recently installed VS Code on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. We did this by installing the rpm and then adding the path to PATH.

When I start code it works fine except that there is no menu bar. (So I can't check the version).

I have tried toggling the 'View: Toggle Menu Bar' command in the command palette (F1) but that doesn't help.  Hitting ALT takes me to an Ubuntu 'Type your command' window.

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Actually, hitting ALT does normally display the menu in the desktop top title bar (I forgot that Ubuntu doesn't display the menu in the application window) but the menu is only shown while ALT is pressed. Is that correct?

Comment: Pressing `ALT` opens the `Run your command` in `Ubuntu 16.10`

Comment: Setting custom Window:Title bar Style solved the issue on my Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 6):

1. click on settings (left)
2. search **Window:Title**
3. change **Window: Title Bar Style** *native* to *custom*

[image]